# MassTransit: multiple consumers, separate queues/endpoints, messages not delivered

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I've got 2 services set up to receive the same message, e.g. `ConsumerA : IConsumer<IMessageA>` and `ConsumerB : IConsumer<IMessageA>`. Each service sets up a unique endpoint, e.g. `queue_a` and `queue_b` and registers its consumer. I see in RabbitMQ an exchange for IMessageA that is of type fanout and bound to `queue_a` and `queue_b`. So far, so good.

- I run both services and publish a message, but only service A is gets it.
- I stop service A and manually publish a message to B in RabbitMQ (service A is a web service that publishes `IMessageA` in response to a POST using `IRequestClient<IMessageA, IMessageAResponse>`, which I why I need to manually post) and now service B gets the message and consumes it as expected.

To be clear, with service A stopped, the message is routed by RabbitMQ to both `queue_a` **and** `queue_b`. If service A is running, the message **only** goes to `queue_b` in spite of exchange bindings existing showing that `queue_b` is bound to the `IMessageA` exchange and absolutely **should** be getting them. Or at least by the time I'm able to examine RabbitMQ through the management web UI, there is no evidence there was ever a message delivered to `queue_b` (i.e. nothing in `queue_b_error` or `queue_b_skipped`, the latter not even existing).

I've added `IReceiveObserver` to both service A and B but nothing is triggering `ReceiveFault` or `ConsumeFault`.

The consumer in service A is basically doing:

```
var result = await MethodThatReturnsIMessageAResponse(messageA);
context.Respond(result);
```

Why is service A interfering with delivery of messages to service B? Where do I even begin looking?

Comment: Have you checked the bindings? This stuff always works, this is a basic functionality. Have you tried throwing an exception in this A service and see if the message goes to the error queue?

Comment: Also, you say that if the service A is stopped and you publish messages, they come to the queue. So what happens to these messages when you start the service? They disappear from the queue, meaning they were consumed?

Comment: When service A is stopped, if I manually publish a message to the `IMessageA` exchange directly in RabbitMQ, it is delivered to both `queue_a` and `queue_b` and service B is able to receive the message and consume it. If I start up service A after that, it picks up the message and processes/consumes it. It is only when service A is running that the messages don't get to `queue_b`. You will see in the first paragraph of my question that I have checked and the bindings do appear to be correct, which I why I'm at a loss about what the problem is.

Comment: Are you able to put this on Github?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am going to try to create an independent repro that I can, although I suspect that's going to "just work"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was "publishing" the messages using:

```
c.Resolve<IBus>().CreateRequestClient<IToDoMessage, IToDoMessageResponse>(new Uri(QueueAddress + QueueName),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

which requires a specific enpoint (e.g. queue name). Instead, I needed to use `CreatePublishRequestClient`:

```
c.Resolve<IBus>().CreatePublishRequestClient<IToDoMessage, IToDoMessageResponse>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

which uses the bus to publish, and goes through the exchange, not to a specific queue. It doesn't help that the [GitHub sample project](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse/blob/master/src/Client/Program.cs#L63) shows the former...